# How to cover the top and bottom of a piece with a self-leveling epoxy resin?

Tags: finishing, finish-selection, epoxy

Is there a good way to cover both the top and bottom of a piece with a self-leveling epoxy resin?  I have a small box/basket that I'd like to have in my kitchen to hold cooking oils.  Since the bottles will likely leak cooking oil, I'd like to treat the wood with an epoxy resin, so that it will be durable and more easily cleaned.  And, it case it's not clear, by epoxy resin I mean a material similar to what's used to finish bar tops.  Anyway, all of the resources I see on using epoxy resin cover finishing the top and sides of the piece.  Basically, we pour and spread the resin on the top and it runs over the side.  What's not clear to me is what to use on the bottom of the piece.  Can we use the epoxy resin on the bottom as well?  If so, it's not clear to me how to accomplish this.  Every piece I've seen has drips from the epoxy along the bottom.  I suppose we could sand these drips down, but then we'll have the same issue when we flip over the piece and treat the bottom.  Certainly, I could use a different product on the bottom, but I'd rather just use the same durable finish on all sides.  Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't need to coat the bottom, but if you *want* to just do it as a second operation and tape the sides to create a dam. BTW epoxy is overkill for this, varnish or shellac would be sufficient to seal off the wood.

Comment: Varnish or shellac would be easier to apply and give the same ammount of protection.

Comment: @mickburkejnr They would provide sufficient protection, but that's not to say they'd provide the same amount. Few things can compete with a pour-on finish for protection, one application can be equivalent to the thickness of over 20 coats of varnish and in addition they're typically harder and less permeable.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see to do it is to thicken the epoxy with something like   colloidal thickening silica, but every thikener shoul work reasonabily well, until it is thick as a filler and then apply it with a spatula in a thin layer, wait until the epoxy is almost cured and then apply another layer (for the workability time refer to the resin manufacturer instructions). This way you can also add some dye to have a particular color, if you like

Be sure that the epoxy is resistant to the UV rays, else it will become yellow-ish after some time, and it is not really nice.